# Next-auth token encoding causing 401's for api calls

Tags: reactjs, jwt, next-auth

So I have a mostly working setup with a `[...nextauth]` that looks like the below. The main issue being that when I call my API, I'm getting a 401. My api is set up fine as I can hit it with any other clients using the same credentials, but it seems to be due to the way that my token is being encoded in the cookie? Seems like I might have to do a custom encode/decode, but I've never had to do that with any other setup in the past.

Anyone run into this before? I would expect to just put the access token in the http only + secure cookie and the browser would just pass that along for me, but seems like there are extra steps I'm missing for this.

`[...nextauth]`

```
import { clients } from "@/lib/axios";
import { env } from "@/utils/environmentService";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import querystring from "query-string";

// For more information on each option (and a full list of options) go to
// https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth
  providers: [
    {
      id: "oidc",
      name: "OIDC",
      type: "oauth",
      wellKnown: `${env.clientUrls.authServer()}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      authorization: {
        params: { scope: "openid email profile recipe_management" },
      },
      idToken: true,
      checks: ["pkce", "state"],
      clientId: "recipe_management.next",
      clientSecret: env.auth.secret,
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
        };
      },
    },
  ],
  events: {
    async signOut({ token }) {
      var refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      let headers = { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };
      try {
        await clients.authServer.post(
          `/protocol/openid-connect/logout`,
          querystring.stringify({
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            client_secret: env.auth.secret,
            client_id: "recipe_management.next",
          }),
          { headers }
        );
      } catch (e) {}
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_at * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        };
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        return token;
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.error = token.error;

      return session;
    },
  },
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `__Secure-next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: env.isDevelopment ? "lax" : "strict",
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
      },
    },
    callbackUrl: {
      name: `__Secure-next-auth.callback-url`,
      options: {
        sameSite: env.isDevelopment ? "lax" : "strict",
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
      },
    },
    csrfToken: {
      name: `__Host-next-auth.csrf-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: env.isDevelopment ? "lax" : "strict",
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
      },
    },
  },
};

/**
 * Takes a token, and returns a new token with updated
 * `accessToken` and `accessTokenExpires`. If an error occurs,
 * returns the old token and an error property
 */
async function refreshAccessToken(token: JWT) {
  try {
    var params = querystring.stringify({
      client_secret: env.auth.secret,
      client_id: "recipe_management.next",
      grant_type: "refresh_token",
      refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
    });
    const url =
      env.clientUrls.authServer() + "/protocol/openid-connect/token?" + params;

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      method: "POST",
    });

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens;
    }

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_at * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    };
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

The token outputs look like this:

`__Secure-next-auth.session-token`

```
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..JxmjRnzY6T7euTwe.0I2zku0JKJcWi_pY_ryewr2xEBgGXjDxh82VTB7k9Ed5uKtBQA-c7KIl6ShwHyWMxTMSIqzxZhsDFihuUULNB4uQUH2ic0nrWV8R_BLfx9xP92xHe7RW_OwtWQyvVAaeWfysAbWyPW167nVv2VL_mX3ubJRi09jEPA9KIm6S9EJQlM7VU9U7mLJ2VQUa7X9kGRH5xmZ05zexNg-MVPe8anMZOjpsedYYrSpfojCrpBQsCzzROkbY6ig1P2s1dBRIQA1juWG8CidVjN_fFeqJC19DyNJ8XAzGWX5xD317MRAlWHIl_Ehi6eYbjbiHFou5mBXSwTf62FT2aGqNUvAqlTi_em6jQ8RaKfnqZ4rBhfak3W5_QdULfUmqL7LQVc3X9ldVsN5M-h2ETemIMeWuKHL0iUBL2TKapPGaaskuYkGDN_LO5jYkAGyT0-QQRAsskzazpbz9_a6NiWnALFUxxTJLkF0LX6ItLUMQYqV8ywqMbJzFugbyzbYDXuPBfizeo2QYWXv9rs3cjXH7RY-7psCQQQhsvu2zJL1Jp465s-bMnCabxltoqAEdW0gexX3OISJgozxOLIvyDBDTcWKDyFUEAaZ9hld4CgpoV1Pk6jarL5-gjSbmDvzuQkc9vKltW9dOtDiubdFzv5bK_MPvOVpe5HOeEyGo8giyUeKX-AhFCFgvvUWS5RUaW-oiqfrX-E1OZqttO8u1tR4JYUSqLe48Z7EQGtWYDwyk6foLXdpYnQdfPox_lbeEKxpb1-6X_dg2Bm7RgCbN4XyTdmeLnXWC6FdY10AAxvS_iRC9pXcpp-lPLdfY6UuhkmNwxynYagJP6QGD4A-N96a14Ly6GvPxwA7_DcRN0KZ0f2fz0nqI_KF4EZGjKhLr2uEnkPoNtiYO4cCTwG_n4ulSRBnBuisMGbCfd11617hPuRv7nSadQmOwisSIOesJtpMHlQ4HsBCVHf36JEFsdSzGPPZgjRrucfl1eiWANbfTH9hnj7_MfHxBpk3royG3T6BzXBlyy65da-4iZBryw8hDglhsSoWa1Ihbxrm__E2Eob2XZxA2LlSHNqeq-6M6SK1OoEL6ZaLEoq082T-ENVyIj2ZnsqjbqLJUFA5byBDjvTRT01UEfTG2GlXSV2Y2OLOaWCj9WBMe4ejTFncbjd4HC3rySTKl71kYsE_SEYfRg0QgAszr7fdhxOvyjgJ27Xc3B7wGVoSjpTlQLcMGpMZkBs71fo7bkqbw_lxwSQ03ajIWBj2r7wrSIYolK8ZgH1-6leT7qzLve_c5N1jOL5Nc7bOKlLEkiJnwj9euHx-ubPlC31bjkejI85NjwKKsBllLoRUs5nruOrfjg20tN0s_mQIgvB7L4K-T8sVS4bGpsis_z3X00MaMyfZV8nMQDAAT0foJ3E9FmLK-bTsFOulXWiF9RKQNdb703Jk2VMrEE5lgVGWwmo_U2mLHhbhMnY_qjOHOs0UH2oeY43BujwLplct-t8gV8Tmnt4gxKjdZSZI9bBTP5p9i31hSwEt4zTgMGuiuk4kuupZP2b-3vp7Q0wpqtG95XoA_z04XfDK5jDXVT1Fq7VtH2HeACqhIPKuqcMYMP0NZ5MK3V-0ZhgyHuh8nNF_jeayI9ES2blJcNqAU9eP-dMhNf1rhTNHhNu5SCNKrv-KDoDPix1JP_8NSVt9TeLzMrN0HMgtTijhLCpYtzndCaQfdf9WlC93N2hxhLY44YwAIC24JZcrRlgf3DdHHwn6h1be3UlsYKRlnV0fQfevtY43Xg_pfNkZT0kHB1rNkA8CiJ_9NzanqdbyrAZJvhK2eCM4rPQ07wVQmtb2OQXeLdoQaqKZZxhpgJ8SpQcD06BAuo45747oSsu2c4QnnTlNAkDTcFb1izYUA-e8Lvu1Y_D16EpNb0R7qkxd4-DZE9BB-8N8gHN_r0HRl-jW2oJQL2ME5N9D3xSJFsMns3kkCRxA_Cv543zvoBHpdec4NgUxE8THp2okji8enDKeXQ5CUX8qqAmtWXLs339A5Cv8QTwBc154ZVGtjU-AZJSKz_4lu3MqQ1gkjDu8U0fKa9bu6rxdKyzq9nAvHCc7GmZeVM2CgoMI68oDGHWnRFDRlZe6l1DAeM5RHds3kJkeLRQ166hFdIs_Ivf07lZXLNzLidnV2qjLPLHN3Jh95wIU3fnkg54Xp5dmEfke8vJm9-d0LAFFxBgtBGLpgixzmOfFwTRbmpTUlVQ5gnpnmMjt-Ec4DaB2blHX4LE7RzNzbui-mWnEeQT7T3FnzUzraCJr7vkdm5yEXjY6B6vJslIeDPGf_LlGxhlPibpt07i140-EX6Et_z-DLYGD7v_kGOVaeMCtzWlxqIzGKlkqtS7nw5nZnaKDKGDH1m68ZO_sF-WzZGaPuMcHw4_kxi3dIVPMP8pDwKwEm9EaSCZaQWJRadyz3DaxLaYrtF-2XrEa8mPuzi1arpN1kgKJf-kj1d2X8EgKru8orssl3XaWyz4lYZziuNCe0nqxHr8aHqoNtOB3K_AauvzvljIzcPwNxnvXuP6KThE5S4TVxuZz1TKChiGRd8FF1A0fHstE2uNryXiwKgyEjqaCD59DUlq3y__C3FoUbYjDj5XcCdnw4sR_6PnUA__SaAO1Iet7RxpQLjCJyWkD_aLVS-bcvF3lmTf0wQDIDyrrR5bDv7vb8wmAXufUOLSHZ2r7P2lEfROijmEMdHmYXxHTsbYVs2s9ukP3QKCTvCkUQFtCPoflbbSL08HKvPFtnAmNwdRZK69wBlrxjsVqbAcpn75A9qXSn-YMbl6TvH6BXnCby_c3Pc7iylWmqVfTz8JxFhgTNtrdicz4TIZJi23j_qTB_fnXlOYOcSoA6BISSutCLzDy2HjD6JdHgaN3wbOfo2Nl6LdgfEIDw96ZiW8M7wg7tESY_MexR9-_rgcRvyiVHCKkPCEv3-wCQWISvkzKBGFpzUYnUuWP6VItKCrzK20sTyShdJZuhSUKw2Jr_xLDPv4TTIGzb29sreuoK3OFqhl9t_8Q1MpCNr3XGQHPHOY8QBjvYrfxf1sMFM_jfRQdTH6eC6iv-LbooriZHKwXSEAVifXn2EQdCksvv5gLP.BZmHIyTuTpe3L2MkSlWaDA
```

`__Host-next-auth.csrf-token`

```
aebde1a59a6e021acf44aa36ea973083fbe652d9a2272dbd46282c55931e3721%7C7177a554e51e04402a910090162398b6553dd764248e4e1852de152a15769bf3
```

`__Secure-next-auth.callback-url`

```
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8582%2Frecipes
```

Comment: Have you discovered any leads on this?

Comment: clerk.dev is doing exact same thing for me. My api routes are 401 and I can't seem to fix it. Not yet anyway.

Comment: You might need to include credentials and make sure you’re sending up a bearer token https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included